# unsuccessful sudo apt-get update not working

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

still new to Linux and trying out Ubuntu. Was able to get it installed however when I tried updating in terminal with $`sudo apt-get update` I would get the following:

```
wave@Wave:~$ sudo apt-get update    
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)   
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/   
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)  
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Software centre or synaptic opened?? close  those two and try!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` (`man lsof`) will show all processes that have the file open. On my system (YMMV), with `synaptic` running:

```
$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
synaptic 14382 root   15uW  REG    8,6        0 424990 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```